# How convert time and date - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working in React and I have an array of data called `this.state.candidate` and I am currently mapping the information to display it in a data table. One of the parameters `item.updated_at` is formatted as `"2019-08-06 13:52:43"`. I want to be able to convert this time to something like this `"8/6/2019, 1:52:43 PM"`. How would I work around doing this. From my understanding this is possible by doing the following, although I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my code.

```
var date = new Date("2019-08-06 13:52:43");
date.toLocaleString();      // "8/6/2019, 1:52:43 PM"
```

This is a snippet of the code that I have:

```
const dataTable = this.state.candidate.map((item) => {
            return {
                id: item.id,
                name: item.name,
                current_company_name: item.current_company_name,
                job: item.job_title,
                owner: item.owner.name,
                updated: item.updated_at,
                email: item.email,
                phone: item.phone,
                is_active: item.is_active,
                is_snoozed: item.is_snoozed,
            };
        });
```

Comment: `updated: new Date(item.updated_at).toLocaleString(),`

Comment: Always save dates in a universal format, like "2019-08-06 13:52:43", so you can recreate it. Only use 'toLocaleString' when you display the date.

Comment: search for "parse" and "format" of JS Date

Comment: thank you @ChrisG that answered my question

Comment: @marlo Given that this is primarily a syntax question, and not so much one about dates specifically, I'm not sure that dupe applies here

Answer (score 0):

Code would be like:

```js
const dataTable = this.state.candidate.map(item=>{
  const dt = new Date(item.updated);
  return {
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    current_company_name: item.current_company_name,
    job: item.job_title,
    owner: item.owner.name,
    updated: dt.toLocaleString(),
    email: item.email,
    phone: item.phone,
    is_active: item.is_active,
    is_snoozed: item.is_snoozed
  };   
});
```